# Remove controller 'Home' from URL in MVC 5

Tags: controller, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I need to remove the controller 'Home' from the URL of my project, now it looks like this: example.com/Home/contact and i want it to look like this: example.com/contact (also for other sections as services, our-team, gallery, etc.)

I tried to remove the '{controller}' that appears before '{action}/{id}' in RouteConfig.cs code, like this:

```
namespace myproject
{
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
    }
}
```

And the controller 'Home' disappears from the URL, but the following links to login and Manage do not work:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login here", "Login", "Account")
@Html.ActionLink("Manage website", "Index", "Manage")
```

How could i make those links work without displaying the controller 'Home' in the URL?

Comment: You'll need to add an additional rule for those controller routes. See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the following to your RouteConfig.cs

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "contact",
        url: "contact",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Contact" }
    );
```

Make sure that the "Default" route mapping is the last one.